# Docker-compose Postgres Spring Kotlin

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, flyway

Trying to make two docker-compose files one for postgres and other one for my application. I am not really strong at docker, but I spent the whole day tryna to solve this issue.
type this commands

docker-compose -f docker-compose-local.yml up

docker-compose -f docker-compose-database.yml up

docker-compose-database.yml starts correctly and i even connected in intelij to this container[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoRVj.png)? but when i try to start docker-compose-local i have this.

docker-compose-local.yml
!!!
version: '3.5'

```
services:
  postback-notifications-service:
    container_name: postback-notifications-service
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - BASE_APP=postback-notifications-app
        - DOCKER_REGISTRY=registry.hub.docker.com
    environment:
      - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev"
      - "POSTGRES_HOST=127.0.0.1" // tryed postback_notifications_service/postgres - don't work
      - "POSTGRES_PORT=5003"
      - "POSTGRES_DATABASE=postback_notifications_service"
      - "POSTGRES_DATABASE_SСHEMA=public"
      - "POSTGRES_USER_NAME=notif-service"
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=notif-service"
    networks:
      - postback-notifications-service
    ports:
      - "11002:11002"
      - "12002:12002"
    restart: always

networks:
  postback-notifications-service:
    external: true
```

!!!!
docker-compose-database
!!!!
version: '3.5'

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postback-notifications-database
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: notif-service
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: notif-service
      POSTGRES_DB: postback_notifications_service
    networks:
      - postback-notifications-service
    ports:
      - "5003:5432"
    restart: always


networks:
  postback-notifications-service:
    external: true
```

!!!!
application-dev.yaml
!!!!

```
database:
  host: ${POSTGRES_HOST:localhost}
  port: ${POSTGRES_PORT:5003}
  name: ${POSTGRES_DATABASE:postback_notifications_service}
  schema: ${POSTGRES_DATABASE_SСHEMA:public}
  user: ${POSTGRES_USER_NAME:notif-service}
  password: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:notif-service}

spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: off
  application:
    name: 'postback-notifications-service'
  r2dbc:
    url: 'r2dbc:postgresql://${POSTGRES_HOST}:${POSTGRES_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DATABASE}?schema=${POSTGRES_DATABASE_SСHEMA}'
    username: '${POSTGRES_USER_NAME}'
    password: '${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}'
  flyway:
    enabled: 'true'
    url: 'jdbc:postgresql://${POSTGRES_HOST}:${POSTGRES_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DATABASE}'
    user: '${POSTGRES_USER_NAME}'
    password: '${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}'
    default-schema: '${POSTGRES_DATABASE_SСHEMA}'

app:
  grpc-port: 12003
  http-port: 11003
  grpc-clients:
    conversions-host: localhost:12012
    partners-host: localhost:12001
    postbacks-host: localhost:12003
  kafka:
    brokers: localhost:9092
```

!!!!!
application.yml
!!!!

```
database:
  host: ${POSTGRES_HOST:localhost}
  port: ${POSTGRES_PORT:5432}
  name: ${POSTGRES_DATABASE:postback_notifications_service}
  schema: ${POSTGRES_DATABASE_SСHEMA:public}
  user: ${POSTGRES_USER_NAME:postback_notifications_service}
  password: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:postback_notifications_service}

spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: off
  application:
    name: 'postback-notifications-service'
  r2dbc:
    url: 'r2dbc:postgresql://${database.host}:${database.port}/${database.name}?schema=${database.schema}'
    username: '${database.user}'
    password: '${database.password}'
  flyway:
    enabled: 'true'
    url: 'jdbc:postgresql://${database.host}:${database.port}/${database.name}'
    user: '${spring.r2dbc.username}'
    password: '${spring.r2dbc.password}'
    default-schema: '${database.schema}'
app:
  grpc-port: ${GRPC_PORT:9090}
  http-port: ${HTTP_PORT:8080}
  instance: ${HOSTNAME:unknown}
  postback-retry-attempts: ${POSTBACK_RETRY_ATTEMPTS:15}
  postback-pending-expiration: ${POSTBACK_PENDING_EXPIRATION:PT10M}
  grpc-clients:
    conversions-host: ${CPA_CONVERSIONS_SERVICE_HOST:localhost:9090}
    partners-host: ${CPA_PARTNERS_SERVICE_HOST:localhost:9090}
  kafka:
    brokers: ${KAFKA_BROKERS:localhost:9092}
```

LOGGS OF docker-compose-local.yml on screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN2QW.png)

Comment: Is there a specific reason you've separated the application and its database into separate Compose files?  You seem to have included a link to an image instead of the output of your container; can you [edit] the question to replace the image link with the actual plain-text logs?